# Angular-cli project can't load fontawesome in SharePoint

Tags: angular, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, angular-cli, sharepoint-online

I have built an application with Angular 4.3.3 and CLI version 1.2.7 that can run in SharePoint. This application depends on FontAwesome for icons.

When running `ng serve` there's no problem with showing the FontAwesome icons. However, when building for a production environment they are not shown.

The Angular application is part of a product that can be installed by customers. They all have their own SharePoint environments. The bundled files are retrieved by the SharePoint WebPart through an IIS website.

I'm able to load these files so my application works for every customer, but as I already said the FontAwesome icons aren't displayed because it tries to load the woff2, woff and ttf files relative to the SharePoint site url.

This is the error:
[image: This is the error]

As you can see in the image above, the files are loaded relative to `glen2013/sites/AdventureWorks2014`. The IIS website that is serving the font files and bundled application files is not on the `glen2013` server but a different server. I know that I can use the `deployUrl` option in the CLI to specify path from where the files are served, but the url from where the files are served change from customer to customer. Each customer has it's own `deployUrl` but I don't want to force a business user to change the `.angular-cli.json` file and open a command prompt to trigger a production build of the application.

Can someone help me out to achieve this at runtime?

**Build command**

`ng build -e prod --no-sourcemap`

**dist folder contents**

- favicon.ico
- fontawesome-webfont.674f50d287a8c48dc19b.eot
- fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749.svg
- fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2
- fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf
- fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff
- index.html
- inline.bundle.js
- main.bundle.js
- polyfills.bundle.js
- scripts.bundle.js
- styles.bundle.js
- vendor.bundle.js

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "obiz-theme.scss",
  "../node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
],
```

**ng -v output**

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.7
node: 8.0.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/common: 4.3.3
@angular/compiler: 4.3.3
@angular/core: 4.3.3
@angular/forms: 4.3.3
@angular/http: 4.3.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.3
@angular/platform-server: 4.3.3
@angular/router: 4.3.3
@angular/cli: 1.2.7
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the assets property in angular-cli.json to copy all of font awesome to your build directory. This makes all the files (css + font files) available in the build.

```
// angular-cli.json
"assets": [
    {"glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/font-awesome", "output": "./font-awesome/"}
]
```

Now you can access it from index.html

```
// index.html
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here are the docs for the cli to copy assets from outside of your project. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md

Comment: The files that I need are already in the dist folder. I've updated my question with the command that I'm using and the dist folder contents.

Comment: @GStaes and your font-awesome.css is requesting those font files? I'd recommend the above just to keep the folder structure the same. font-awesome.css is trying to load resources relative to itself ('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0')

Comment: I got it to work by adding the style link dynamically to the page.

Comment: @GStaes can you give example of how you did it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I agree with LLai.When When I upgraded @angular/cli to version 1.3.0,I also made this mistake.Now I've solved it.
1.Copy fontawesome to src/assets
2.Add it to index.html
  
3.modify configuration file .angular-cli.json 
      "assets": [
        {"glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/font-awesome", "output": "./font-awesome/"}
      ],
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ],